# How to use Monte Carlo for ARIMA Simulation Function in R

Tags: r, montecarlo, arima

Here is the algorithm of what I want to do with R:

1. Simulate 10 time series data set from `ARIMA` model through `arima.sim()` function
2. Split the series into sub-series of possible `2s`, `3s`, `4s`, `5s`, `6s`, `7s`, `8s`, and `9s`.
3. For each size take a resample the blocks with replacement, for new series and obtain the best `ARIMA` model from the subseries from each block size through `auto.arima()` function.
4. Obtain for each subseries of each block sizes `RMSE`.

The below `R` function get that done.

```
## Load packages and prepare multicore process
library(forecast)
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
n_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores())
## simulate ARIMA(1,0, 0)
#n=10; phi <- 0.6; order <- c(1, 0, 0)
bootstrap1 <- function(n, phi){
  ts <- arima.sim(n, model = list(ar=phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
  ########################################################
  ## create a vector of block sizes
  t <- length(ts)    # the length of the time series
  lb <- seq(n-2)+1   # vector of block sizes to be 1 < l < n (i.e to be between 1 and n exclusively)
  ########################################################
  ## This section create matrix to store block means
  BOOTSTRAP <- matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = length(lb))
  colnames(BOOTSTRAP) <-lb
  ########################################################
  ## This section use foreach function to do detail in the brace
  BOOTSTRAP <- foreach(b = 1:length(lb), .combine = 'cbind') %do%{
    l <- lb[b]# block size at each instance 
    m <- ceiling(t / l)                                 # number of blocks
    blk <- split(ts, rep(1:m, each=l, length.out = t))  # divides the series into blocks
    ######################################################
    res<-sample(blk, replace=T, 10)        # resamples the blocks
    res.unlist <- unlist(res, use.names = FALSE)   # unlist the bootstrap series
    train <- head(res.unlist, round(length(res.unlist) - 10)) # Train set
    test <- tail(res.unlist, length(res.unlist) - length(train)) # Test set
    nfuture <- forecast::forecast(train, model = forecast::auto.arima(train), lambda=0, biasadj=TRUE, h = length(test))$mean        # makes the `forecast of test set
    RMSE <- Metrics::rmse(test, nfuture)      # RETURN RMSE
    BOOTSTRAP[b] <- RMSE
  }
  BOOTSTRAPS <- matrix(BOOTSTRAP, nrow = 1, ncol = length(lb))
  colnames(BOOTSTRAPS) <- lb
  BOOTSTRAPS
  return(list(BOOTSTRAPS))
}
```

Calling the function

```
bootstrap1(10, 0.6)
```

I get the below result:

```
##              2        3         4        5        6        7         8         9
##  [1,] 0.8920703 0.703974 0.6990448 0.714255 1.308236 0.809914 0.5315476 0.8175382
```

I want to repeat the above `step 1` to `step 4` chronologically, then I think of `Monte Carlo` technology in `R`. Thus, I load its package and run the below function:

```
param_list=list("n"=10, "phi"=0.6)
library(MonteCarlo)
MC_result<-MonteCarlo(func = bootstrap1, nrep=3, param_list = param_list)
```

expecting to get a like of the below result in `matrix` form:

```
##           [,2]     [,3]      [,4]    [,5]       [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]
##  [1,] 0.8920703 0.703974  0.6990448 0.714255  1.308236  0.809914  0.5315476 0.8175382
##  [2,] 0.8909836 0.8457537 1.095148  0.8918468 0.8913282 0.7894167 0.8911484 0.8694729
##  [3,] 1.586785  1.224003  1.375026  1.292847  1.437359  1.418744  1.550254  1.30784
```

but I get the following error message:

> Error in MonteCarlo(func = bootstrap1, nrep = 3, param_list = param_list) :
> func has to return a list with named components. Each component has to be scalar.

How can I find my way to obtain a desired result like the above and make the result reproducible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get this error message because MonteCarlo expects `bootstrap1()` to accept *one* parameter combination for the simulation and that it only returns *one* value (`RMSE`) per replication. This is not the case here since the block length (`lb`) is determined by the length of the simulated time series (`n`) *within* `bootstrap1` and so you will get results for `n - 2` block lengths for each call.

A solution is to pass the block length as a parameter and rewrite `bootstrap1()` appropriately:

```r
library(MonteCarlo)
library(forecast)
library(Metrics)

# parameter grids
n <- 10 # length of time series
lb <- seq(n-2) + 1 # vector of block sizes
phi <- 0.6 # autoregressive parameter
reps <- 3 # monte carlo replications

# simulation function  
bootstrap1 <- function(n, lb, phi) {
    
    #### simulate ####
    ts <- arima.sim(n, model = list(ar = phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
    
    #### devide ####
    m <- ceiling(n / lb) # number of blocks
    blk <- split(ts, rep(1:m, each = lb, length.out = n)) # divide into blocks
    #### resample ####
    res <- sample(blk, replace = TRUE, 10)        # resamples the blocks
    res.unlist <- unlist(res, use.names = FALSE)   # unlist the bootstrap series
    #### train, forecast ####
    train <- head(res.unlist, round(length(res.unlist) - 10)) # train set
    test <- tail(res.unlist, length(res.unlist) - length(train)) # test set
    nfuture <- forecast(train, # forecast
                        model = auto.arima(train), 
                        lambda = 0, biasadj = TRUE, h = length(test))$mean    
    ### metric ####
    RMSE <- rmse(test, nfuture) # return RMSE
    return(
      list("RMSE" = RMSE)
    )
}

param_list = list("n" = n, "lb" = lb, "phi" = phi)
```

To run the simulation, pass the parameters as well as `bootstrap1()` to `MonteCarlo()`. For the simulation to be carried out in parallel you need to set the number of cores via `ncpus`. The MonteCarlo package uses snowFall, so it should run on Windows.

Note that I also set `raw = T` (otherwise the outcomes would be averages over all replications). Setting the seed before will make the results reproducible.

```r
set.seed(123)
MC_result <- MonteCarlo(func = bootstrap1, 
                        nrep = reps,
                        ncpus = parallel::detectCores() - 1,
                        param_list = param_list,
                        export_also = list(
                         "packages" = c("forecast", "Metrics")
                        ),
                        raw = T)
```

The result is an array. I think it's best to transform it into a data.frame via `MakeFrame()`:

```r
Frame <- MakeFrame(MC_result)
```

It's easy to get a `reps x lb` matrix though:

```r
matrix(Frame$RMSE, ncol = length(lb), dimnames = list(1:reps, lb))
```

Comment: I need to invite you to a room on issues that go beyond the scope of this question which you have answered. I do not even know how to send an invitation to that effect. I searched for your username with this link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=all&sort=name but can not find you. I will not mind if you can invite me.

Comment: Please join me here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222902/room-for-daniel-james-and-m-a