# Make my Two Different R Functions to be Just One Function

Tags: r, function, montecarlo

I want to use `MonteCarlo` function in `MonteCarlo` package in `R` which has one requirement among others as supply `just one single function` into the `MonteCarlo` package.

> To run a simulation study, the user has to nest both - the generation of a sample and the calculation of the desired statistics from this sample - in a single function. This function is passed to MonteCarlo(). No additional programming is required ([Vignette: The MonteCarlo Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MonteCarlo/vignettes/MonteCarlo-Vignette.html)).

Contrary to this vital condition, I have two different functions that suit my algorithm. I have used the `MonteCarlo` function as provided by the correct answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222355/how-to-use-monte-carlo-for-arima-simulation-function-in-r-on-windows) for a method.

I want to use a different method thus, I write the following functions (function1 and function2) for it to be passed to `MonteCarlo` function as demonstrated below:

Here is the algorithm of what I want to do with `R`:

1. Simulate 10 time series data set from `ARIMA` model through `arima.sim()` function
2. Split the series into **overlapping** sub-series of possible `2s`, `3s`, `4s`, `5s`, `6s`, `7s`, `8s`, and `9s`.
3. For each size take a resample the blocks with replacement, for new series and obtain the best `ARIMA` model from the subseries from each block size through `auto.arima()` function.
4. Obtain for each subseries of each block sizes `RMSE`.

The below `R` functions get that done.

```
library(MonteCarlo)
library(forecast)
library(Metrics)
############################################
function1 <- function(lb, ov, n) {

  starts <- unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, lb), seq(lb-ov+1, n, lb))))
  ends <- pmin(starts + lb - 1, n)

  # truncate starts and ends to the first num elements
  num <- match(n, ends)
  head(data.frame(starts, ends), num)
}
#############################################
# parameter grids
n <- 10 # length of time series
lb <- seq(n-2) + 1 # vector of block sizes
phi <- 0.6 # autoregressive parameter
reps <- 3 # monte carlo replications

# simulation function  
function2 <- function(n, lb, phi) {

  #### simulate ####
  ov <- ceiling(lb/2)
  vblocks <- Vectorize(function1, c("lb", "ov"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  d <- vblocks(lb = lb, ov = ov, n = n)
  ts <- arima.sim(n, model = list(ar = phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)

  #### devide ####
  blk <- lapply(d, function(x) with(x, Map(function(i, j) ts[i:j], starts, ends)))
  #### resample ####
  res <- sample(blk, replace = TRUE, 10)        # resamples the blocks
  res.unlist <- unlist(res, use.names = FALSE)   # unlist the bootstrap series
  #### train, forecast ####
  train <- head(res.unlist, round(length(res.unlist) - 10)) # train set
  test <- tail(res.unlist, length(res.unlist) - length(train)) # test set
  nfuture <- forecast(train, # forecast
                      model = auto.arima(train), 
                      lambda = 0, biasadj = TRUE, h = length(test))$mean    
  ### metric ####
  RMSE <- rmse(test, nfuture) # return RMSE
  return(
    list("RMSE" = RMSE)
  )
}

param_list = list("n" = n, "lb" = lb, "phi" = phi)

set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
MC_result <- MonteCarlo(func = bootstrap4, 
                            nrep = reps,
                            ncpus = parallel::detectCores() - 1,
                            param_list = param_list,
                            export_also = list(
                              "packages" = c("forecast", "Metrics")
                            ),
                            raw = T)
```

I got this error as I run the above:

> in snowfall::sfExport("func2", "func", "libloc_strings", "function1",  :
> Unknown/unfound variable ends in export. (local=TRUE)

I want to integrate `function1` into `function2` in a way that `function1` will not be a function in function2.

**here is my trial**

```
function2 <- function(n, lb, phi) {

  #### simulate ####
  ov <- ceiling(lb/2)
  function1 <- head(data.frame(unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, lb), seq(lb-ov+1, n, lb)))), pmin(unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, lb), seq(lb-ov+1, n, lb)))) + lb - 1, n)), match(n, pmin(unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, lb), seq(lb-ov+1, n, lb)))) + lb - 1, n)))
  vblocks <- Vectorize(function1, c("lb", "ov"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  d <- vblocks(lb = lb, ov = ov, n = n)
  ts <- arima.sim(n, model = list(ar = phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)

  #### devide ####
    blk <- lapply(d, function(x) with(x, Map(function(i, j) ts[i:j], unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, lb), seq(lb-ov+1, n, lb)))), pmin(unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, lb), seq(lb-ov+1, n, lb)))) + lb - 1, n))))

  #### resample ####
  res <- sample(blk, replace = TRUE, 10)        # resamples the blocks
  res.unlist <- unlist(res, use.names = FALSE)   # unlist the bootstrap series
  #### train, forecast ####
  train <- head(res.unlist, round(length(res.unlist) - 10)) # train set
  test <- tail(res.unlist, length(res.unlist) - length(train)) # test set
  nfuture <- forecast(train, # forecast
                      model = auto.arima(train), 
                      lambda = 0, biasadj = TRUE, h = length(test))$mean    
  ### metric ####
  RMSE <- rmse(test, nfuture) # return RMSE
  return(
    list("RMSE" = RMSE)
  )
}
```

when I passed it to this:

```
set.seed(123, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
MC_result <- MonteCarlo(func = function2, 
                            nrep = reps,
                            ncpus = parallel::detectCores() - 1,
                            param_list = param_list,
                            export_also = list(
                              "packages" = c("forecast", "Metrics")
                            ),
                            raw = T)
```

I got this error message:

> 3 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "vblocks"

What I did in my trial is just to put the whole of `function1` as a single statement in `function2`

Comment: I am waiting for help on this question.

Comment: If anybody needs further clarification on this problem please ask me through comment line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the contents of `function1` into the body of `function2` - including the variable assignments etc.

```
library(MonteCarlo)
library(forecast)
library(ModelMetrics)

mc_f <- function(n, lb, phi) {
  # Generate data
  ov <- ceiling(lb / 2)
  starts <- unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, lb), seq(lb - ov + 1, n, lb))))
  ends <- pmin(starts + lb - 1, n)
  num <- match(n, ends)
  d <- head(data.frame(starts, ends), num)
  
  ts <- arima.sim(n, model = list(ar = phi, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
  
  blk <- mapply(
    function(start, end) ts[start:end],
    d$starts, 
    d$ends, 
    SIMPLIFY = FALSE
  )
  
  # Resample
  res <- sample(blk, replace = TRUE, 10)
  res.unlist <- unlist(res, use.names = FALSE)
  
  # Train and forecast
  train <- head(res.unlist, round(length(res.unlist) - 10))
  test <- tail(res.unlist, length(res.unlist) - length(train))
  nfuture <- forecast(train,
                      model = auto.arima(train),
                      lambda = 0, biasadj = TRUE, h = length(test))$mean
  
  # Extract metric
  RMSE <- rmse(test, nfuture)
  list("RMSE" = RMSE)
}
```

```
reps <- 3
param_list <- list(n = 10, lb = seq(n - 2) + 1, phi = 0.6)

mc_result <- MonteCarlo(
  func = mc_f,
  nrep = reps,
  ncpus = parallel::detectCores() - 1,
  param_list = param_list
)
#> Grid of  8  parameter constellations to be evaluated. 
#>  
#> Simulation parallelized using 3 cpus. 
#>  
#> Progress: 
#>  
#>   |==================================================================================| 100%
```